# How to remove a class when the date is changed using Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I want to ask how can I remove class when user select date from Datepicker

```
$('#event-date').keyup(function () {
    $("#errorfieldEventDate").removeClass("has-error");
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group" data-bind="fadeVisible: isEventDateVisible">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Event Date:</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" id="event-date" name="event-date" class="date-picker form-control date-picker-view" data-bind="value: eventItem().selectedEventDate" />
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="icon-info icon-info-calendar"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="logo logo-required"></span>
                <span class="data required-box" data-bind="visible: isEventDateError"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you've written?

Comment: @Ninja Developer did something not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to the [`changeDate` event](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/events.html#changedate):

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2qhc0sa9/)

```
$('#event-date').on('changeDate', function (e) {
    $("#errorfieldEventDate").removeClass("has-error");
});
```